# How do i round off float values to integer in karate

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

I have a floating point value of 0.99996 and want to round off to the nearest Integer. How do i do that in karate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
* def val1 = 0.99996
* print val1
* def val2 = Math.round(val1)
* print val2
```

Note that before Karate 1.0 you may need to do this to remove the decimal point:

```
* def val2 = ~~Math.round(val1)
```

Also refer to type-conversion: https://github.com/intuit/karate#floats-and-integers