# Convert all ints to double in Json

Tags: karate

So i get a response from an API as a JSON with all the Numeric values expressed as doubles (The karate default).
Similarly, i get a response from my database which sends out int values (without .0's)

I want to assert these in full using the "match ==" for the whole body (cant use the parse and ~~)

Can we convert the whole JSON's double's into ints in one go?

Comment: yes, use `karate.map()` and refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52072903/143475